# How to test that an API response has keys in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an endpoint that responds with an object's attributes + attributes that are added from an ActiveModelSerializer. I want to write a test that checks to see if the response has keys.

Let's hypothetically say that the object (say a tree) has these keys

`expected_tree_attributes = [:height, :age, :color]`

How do I write this test properly? Can I write:

```
subject { post :obtain_tree_info, { id: tree.id } }

response = JSON.parse(subject.body)
expected(response).to include(*expected_tree_attributes)
```

IS that... acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to use [rspec-api-matchers gem](https://github.com/rspec-api/rspec-api-matchers)

or [airborne gem](https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne)

With these you can do:

```
# api_matchers
response = JSON.parse(subject.body)
expect(response).to be_success
expect(response).to have_json_node(:height).with(tree.height)
expect(response).to have_json_node(:age).with(tree.age)
expect(response).to have_json_node(:color).with(tree.color)

# or

expect(response).to have_json_node(:age).with("123")
```

Airborne

```
describe 'sample spec' do
  it 'should validate types' do
    post '/api/v1/obtain_tree_info', {id: tree.id}
    expect_json_types(height: :int, age: :int_or_null, color: :string)
  end
end
```